# Parsing nmea csv in c++/c for microchip

Tags: c, csv, pic, microchip, nmea

How can I parse a comma separated char string? I've tried using strtok but I can't get it working.

```
     char str2[] = "$GNRMC,011802.00,A,4104.22420,N,08131.66173,W,0.021,,280218,,,D*78\n";


     char *p;

     p = strtok(str2, ",");




       char *input[8];
        int i = 0;
for( i=0;i<8;i++)
   {
    input[i] = p;
    p = strtok(NULL, ",");  

   }
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to set a variable to the string. Such as

```
if (i == 0){
string type = $GNRMC;
}

if (i == 1){
float thisnum = 011802.00
}
```

etc.

This is being written for a pic so I can't use vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You're upper snippet is working for me, besides two minor issues:

- `buf` should be `str2`
- your array of char pointers is too small to hold all substrings

For the second one, you need to convert your substring to the correct type first.

__

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(){

#define NUM_SUBSTRINGS 13

char str2[] = "$GNRMC,011802.00,A,4104.22420,N,08131.66173,W,0.021,,280218,,,D*78\n";
char *p;
p = strtok(str2, ",");

char * input[NUM_SUBSTRINGS];
int i = 0;

for(i=0; i<NUM_SUBSTRINGS; i++)
{   
    char *type = NULL;
    float thisnum = 0.0;
    if (i == 0){
        type = p;
    }

    if (i == 1){
        thisnum = strtof(p, NULL);
    }

    if(p != NULL)
        printf("String %s, type: %s, num: %f\n", p, type, thisnum);

    input[i] = p;
    p = strtok(NULL, ",");  

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this in a MPLAB X simulator?

Comment: Nevermind. My compiler was optimizing variables and not giving me the correct values in the watch screen. Thanks for the help.